# How to inject Feign Client with out using Spring Boot and call a REST Endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have two Java processes - which get spawned from the same Jar using different run configurations

Process A - Client UI component , Developed Using Spring bean xml based approach. No Spring Boot is there.

Process B - A new Springboot Based component , hosts REST End points.

Now from Process A , on various button click how can I call the REST end points on Process B using Feign Client.

Note - Since Process A is Spring XML based , right at the moment we can not convert that to Spring boot. Hence @EnableFeignClients can not be used to initialise the Feign Clients

So Two questions

1) If the above is possible how to do it ?

2) Till Process A is moved to Spring boot - is Feign still an easier option than spring REST template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to just initialise Feign in any code (without spring) just like in the readme example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    GitHub github = Feign.builder()
                     .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                     .target(GitHub.class, "https://api.github.com");
...
}
```

Please take a look at the getting started guide: [feign on github](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign)

Answer (score 3):

[Feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#basics) is a Java to HTTP client binder inspired by Retrofit, JAXRS-2.0, and WebSockets and you can easily use feign without spring boot. And Yes, feign still better option to use because Feign Simplify the HTTP API Clients using declarative way as [Spring REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) does.

1) Define http methods and endpoints in interface.

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
public interface NotificationClient {

    @RequestLine("POST")
    String notify(URI uri, @HeaderMap Map<String, Object> headers, NotificationBody body);
}
```

2) Create Feign client using `Feign.builder()` method.

```
Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(customDecoder())
                .target(Target.EmptyTarget.create(NotificationClient.class));
```

There are various [decoders](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#decoders) available in feign to simplify your tasks.

Comment: @AnirbanBanerjee if it works for you can make answer accepted, this will help others to find the solution to relative problem.